# Is it Possible to Merge Objective-C Project with SwiftUI Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am working on a project with a group of developers. They created a part of the app with objective-C, including UI, model, and controllers. I am using Swift on my end, and recently I've began using SwiftUI. The question, however, is

**is it possible to integrate the Objective-C UI and code into my SwiftUI project. If so, how do I do it?**

By integrating, I mean segueing between view controllers, passing data across view controllers. For example, if I'm creating a dairy app. I used Objective-C to create the table view consisting of daily entries and I used SwiftUI to create the individual daily entry creation page.

**If merging Objective-C and SwiftUI is not possible. Is it possible between Objective-C and Swift?**

Comment: If you are using SwiftUI then make sure your targeted user have ios13 or later

Comment: You can use the concept of bridging header to use objective c code in your swift code.